# Java-How to optimize else if using Map collection in java

Tags: java

Below is my else if ladder.
Please tell me how to optimize else if ladder using Map

```
for (String p1: data) {
    p1 = p1.replace("@", "");
    if (p1.startsWith("Year")) {
        Year = p1.substring(p1.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        System.out.print(Year);
    } else if (p1.startsWith("Department")) {
        Department = p1.substring(p1.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        System.out.print(Department);
    } else if (p1.startsWith("Division")) {
        Division = p1.substring(p1.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        System.out.print(Division);
    } else if (p1.startsWith("Subject Code")) {
        SubjectCode = p1.substring(p1.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        System.out.print(SubjectCode);
    } else if (p1.startsWith("Teacher Code")) {
        int k = p1.indexOf(" ", p1.indexOf(" ") + 1);
        String res = p1.substring(0, k);
        System.out.print("Characters ::" + res);
        String TeacherCode1 = p1.substring(p1.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        int m = TeacherCode1.indexOf(" ", TeacherCode1.indexOf(" ") + 1);
        System.out.println(m);
        TeacherCode = TeacherCode1.substring(0, m);
        System.out.println("Value of p2 ::" + TeacherCode.trim());
    } else if (p1.startsWith("Date")) {
        Date = p1.substring(p1.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        System.out.print(Date);
    }
}
```

The above code is too lengthy.
I want to optimize it for better performance using Map

Now I attached Image file,that i converted into text file using OCR and I wanted to split data,to save into database like Year:THIRD ,Department: INFO. TECH ,Date:18/08/2017,Subject Code: TBGOZ like that But in Optimize code using Map.

[image: Click for Image]

Comment: Do you want to optimize the `p1.startsWith(...)` conditions? Why do you think they don't perform well?

Comment: Do you want to optimize for readability, code size, or code performance? You optimize for these differently.

Comment: If this code works fine, then this question is off topic on Stack Overflow, but may be good for our sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Joe C I think the question is alright, since he asked how to improve the performance with HashMap which he seem to not know how to use it yet. I've provided an extensive answer to that already.

Comment: If you can provide some sample input data then optimization would be easy

Comment: Why did the though of Map for optimization came to your mind?a small explanation of why/how you want to optimize this code with map will be really helpful.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann,yeah I want to optimize code size and performance as well..!!.@Serj you well understood my question,exactly what I want to be.

Comment: @Pramod I have attached Image file pls see it

Comment: @AnupSonkusare
Thanks for sharing.
Please see my answer below. That way you will get a map of Data which you can  save to DB

Answer (score 1):

The logic for Year, Department, Division, Subject Code and Date is the same.

So you can do the other parts first, and then `else` for these common bits

```
if (p1.startsWith("Teacher Code")) {
    int k = p1.indexOf(" ", p1.indexOf(" ") + 1);
    String res = p1.substring(0, k);
    System.out.print("Characters ::" + res);
    String TeacherCode1 = p1.substring(p1.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    int m = TeacherCode1.indexOf(" ", TeacherCode1.indexOf(" ") + 1);
    System.out.println(m);
    TeacherCode = TeacherCode1.substring(0, m);
    System.out.println("Value of p2 ::" + TeacherCode.trim());
} else {
    String other = p1.substring(p1.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    System.out.print(other);
}
```

BTW, "*I want to optimize it for better performance using Map*" - There will be no noticeable performance benefit.

Comment: this is simple and perfect answer

Answer (score 1):

May be following will be helpful:

```
for (String p1: data) 
    {
        p1 = p1.replace("@", "");
        String[] vals = p1.split(":");
        int lastIndx = vals.length-1;
        switch(vals[0])
        {
        case "Year":
            Year = vals[lastIndx];
            System.out.print(Year);
            break;
        case "Department":
            Department = vals[lastIndx];
            System.out.print(Department);
            break;
        case "Division":
            Division = vals[lastIndx];
            System.out.print(Division);
            break;
        case "Subject Code":
            SubjectCode = vals[lastIndx];
            System.out.print(SubjectCode);
            break;
        case "Date":
            Date = vals[lastIndx];
            System.out.print(Date);
            break;
        case "Teacher Code":    
            int k = p1.indexOf(" ", p1.indexOf(" ") + 1);
            String res = p1.substring(0, k);
            System.out.print("Characters ::" + res);
            String TeacherCode1 = vals[lastIndx];;
            int m = TeacherCode1.indexOf(" ", TeacherCode1.indexOf(" ") + 1);
            System.out.println(m);
            TeacherCode = TeacherCode1.substring(0, m);
            System.out.println("Value of p2 ::" + TeacherCode.trim());
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: where did Year,Department,Division... came from ?

Comment: @TmP Isn't is available in OP question?

Comment: the one which you used in case? and you can optimize this code by removing duplicate lines

Comment: @TmP it comes from `p1.split(":")`.

Comment: undeclared fields bro

Comment: Since OP is searching `:` and strings present in `case` (OP is checking via if statement), so I think it is present in `p1`

Comment: Its too lengthy code,that's why I want to reduce and optimize using Map collection framework

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, maps contain key value pairs. In this case, your keys will be strings like `Year`, `Department`, `Division` etc. I suggest you put these strings into an array, except the teacher code because that needs special handling:

```
String[] keys = {"Year", "Department", "Division" ...};
```

Now, create your map:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

You can then loop through this array:

```
for (String key : keys) {
    if (p1.startsWith("Teacher Code")) {
        int k = p1.indexOf(" ", p1.indexOf(" ") + 1);
        String res = p1.substring(0, k);
        System.out.print("Characters ::" + res);
        String TeacherCode1 = p1.substring(p1.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        int m = TeacherCode1.indexOf(" ", TeacherCode1.indexOf(" ") + 1);
        System.out.println(m);
        map.put("Teacher Code", TeacherCode1.substring(0, m));
        System.out.println("Value of p2 ::" + TeacherCode.trim());
    } else if (p1.startsWith(key)) {
        String value = p1.substring(p1.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        map.put(key, value);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If variable assignment is not important. here is how you can generate map.

```
Function<String, String> keyFunction = p1 -> {
    return p1.substring(0, p1.indexOf(":") + 1);
};
Function<String, String> valueFunction = p1 -> {
    return p1.substring(p1.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
};
Map<String, String> map =data.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(keyFunction, valueFunction));
```